# ggplot2 retrieve y axis title for subtitle

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

ggplot2 titles the y-axis with the name of the y variable. e.g., the y-axis has "mpg" as the title in the example below:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = disp, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point()
```

Is there a way to use that string value for the subtitle? Obviously I can pass a new string like so:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = disp, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(subtitle = "mpg")
```

But what I want is a way to point to the string value of the y-axis title. For example, I thought this would work:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = disp, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(subtitle = axis.title.y, y = "")
```

`Error in dots_list(..., title = title, subtitle = subtitle, caption = caption,  :  object 'axis.title.y' not found`

Ultimately I want to remove the y-axis title and use the subtitle to provide the same info, without having to specify the subtitle string each time (just as I don't have to specify the y-axis title string by default).

Thanks for any tips or advice.

Answer (score 2):

Is this the right direction?

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = disp, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point()

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = disp, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(subtitle = p$labels$y, y = "")
```

Or

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = disp, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(subtitle = (ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x = disp, y = mpg)))$labels$y, y = "")
```

[image]

Comment: This a pretty good solution. Ideally it would be neater to reference the y-label without the extra step of declaring p or calling ggplot twice. But maybe that is just not possible in this library